# How to revoke access for trusted devices on outlook.com after having changed the password?

Tags: security, outlook.com, passwords

I changed my outlook.com password, but my surface password and Android smartphone still sync my calendar, although I had not yet entered the new password. How can I revoke access for all devices?

Answer (score 2):

To revoke trusted devices, do the following:

- Go to https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage
- Click on **Remove all the trusted devices associated with my account** under
  Trusted devices section

  [image]

Comment: Sorry. They aren't listed. Neither the Android smartphone with Exchange Active Sync account, nor the Windows RT Surface tablet.

Comment: @chris Updating answer now

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I've already done this. The site says, I don't have to enter my password to access personal information like my credit card. So I'm not sure if this is the right function. Maybe I have to wait a bit longer until access is revoked. I immediately opened the android calendar after changing the password and it synced new appointments.

Comment: My work account takes about an hour or two to realize password change, so maybe all you have to do is wait. Lets wait until my b'day next year

Comment: This remove trusted devices feature is only for a second password request, for example when your credit card number is accessed. I've removed all devices yesterday night and after 12 hours my android is still syncing appointments. At least there is a "last activity" table, so I can see that it's only me who logged in. Nevertheless, that's a security issue and missing feature!

Comment: Trusted device or untrusted, once the password has been changed they should stop syncing unless a new password is provided to it. There seems to be some problem and it is too big to be missed

Comment: Ok, now my Surface tablet has asked for the new password, but the Android device hasn't.